# Get email address from advance find in Outlook's Global Address List (GAL ) by jobtitle

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, gal

I tried this code to find contacts in GAL by jobtitle.

```vb
    Sub FindEmailsByJobTitle()
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim oGAL As Outlook.AddressList
        Dim oContacts As Outlook.AddressEntries
        Dim oContact As Outlook.ContactItem
        Dim oResults As Outlook.Items
        Dim sFilter As String
        Dim sJobTitle As String
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set oGAL = olApp.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")
        sJobTitle = "MANAGER"
        sFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:contacts:JobTitle" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%" & sJobTitle & "%'"
        
        Set oResults = oGAL.AddressEntries.GetFirst().AddressList.Find(sFilter) 'this is error
        
        If Not oResults Is Nothing Then
            For Each oContact In oResults
                Debug.Print oContact.Address
            Next oContact
        Else
            MsgBox "No contacts found."
        End If
        
        Set oResults = Nothing
        Set oContacts = Nothing
        Set oGAL = Nothing
        Set olApp = Nothing
    
    End Sub
```

It throws an error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0):

`AddressEntries` object does not support `Find` method. Generally, search support by the address containers is very basic compared to searching in message store folders (`Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict)`.

The best you can do in OOM is `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` and hope that the given value can be uniquely resolved.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can filter on a few properties explicitly exposed by GAL for searching (Alias, City, Company, Department, First Name, Last Name, Office, Title). This is what you see in the address book window in Outlook if you click "Advanced Find". Redemption exposes it through the [RDOAddressListSearch](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressListSearch.htm) object:

```vb
set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set rAddrList = rSession.Addressbook.GAL
set rSearch = rAddrList.Search
rSearch.Title = "MANAGER"
set rAddressEntries = rSearch.GetResults
for each rAddressEntry in rAddressEntries
    Debug.Print rAddressEntry.Name
next
```

Comment: thanks for respon, i tried that code but i get error "Method and data member not found" at `Session.MAPIOBJECT`,

Comment: Are you running this code in Outlook VBA? Is Application variable initialized?

Comment: Also, try the updated script above - I renamed variables to avoid potential name conflicts with intrinsic Outlook VBA objects and types.

Comment: how to initialization rSession, rAddrList, rSearch ? I am not familiar with RDO

Comment: The script above is self contained, you don't need to add anything as long as Redemption is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddressList` class doesn't provide the `Find` method. You need to iterate over all GAL entries manually or just create a recipient by using the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method of the `Namespace` class. This method is most commonly used to create a Recipient object for use with the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method, for example, to open a delegator's folder. It can also be used to verify a given name against an address book. The name of the recipient can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient. Then you can get a `Recipient` object instance and get the email address.

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
  MsgBox myRecipient.Address 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Otherwise, you need to iterate over all items in the loop and check the [JobTitle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.jobtitle) property of each entry.